# How does Apache know when and how to look for relative paths?

Tags: html, apache

If we have a file structure like so:

```
/
├── aboutus
│   ├── aboutus.html
│   └── logo.jpg
├── validate.php
├── index.html
└── logo.jpg
```

Although one would have to specify the folder when linking to `aboutus.html` ( ie. `<a href="aboutus/aboutus.html">`), in both `index.html` and `aboutus.html` if you place `logo.jpg`, Apache will know which one to load. It probably looks for the file in the current directory only. I have the following directive in my Virtual Host section:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validate.php
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /validate.php?uri=$1
```

I am a total newbie with these rewerite rules, so this is what I *want* the above to do: I want it to intercept any requests from the browser. These include requests entered in the address bar, as well as requests from within web pages (ie. js files, images...). Next I want to send the requested file to `validate.php`

`validate.php` obviously validates the user, but essentially just returns whatever file the user requested. If `aboutus.html` inserts its picture like so `<img src = "logo.jpg"/>`, how can I ensure that `validate.php` returns `/aboutus/logo.jpg` and not `/logo.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the absolute path is determined from the *base resource URL* and a *relative resource URL* (more on this [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2)). For your `validate.php` to be able to properly resolve the relative URLs for images, stylesheets, etc., you should somehow let it know the absolute URL of the document containing these resources (and this is even trickier if the document has the [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag).

Answer (score 1):

Puk, You have to keep two aspect separate:

- Any HTTP request, such as a **GET** are absolute, and the *browser* will convert any relative href or src attributes based on either the path of the referring document (or the path defined in a `<base>` tag) so if you load `http://somehost/fred/xx.html` which then references an image `style1/images/pic.png` then the browser will request  `http://somehost/fred/style1/images/pic.png`
- How mod_rewrite processes paths is quite different. That's the business of the server.  See the [RewriteRule Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) which explains how relative and absolute paths are evaluated inside a per-server configuration (apache.conf or vhost.conf) and inside a Per-directory configuration (e.g. in an `.htaccess` or  block)

Answer (score 0):

Anyways in htaccess file you always work with absolute path. I mean starting with root slash.

try to use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validate.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /validate.php?uri=$1
```